# Python PIP install package errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi, package

I am completely new to Python programming. As what I understand, if I want to install any python packages I need to use `pip install` but seems like there are many troubles for me when downloading some packages.

I met this problem a few times with different kind of packages, at first I like to download the `numpy` but it seems like something wrong with the wheel file but eventually I download that wheel file from "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages".

Now again I am going to download another packages which is **"RPI.GPIO"**, and below is the error I face in the command prompt which I think is similar like the problem I met from the `numpy` installation.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9qms.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX8ma.png)

I tried to search the packages on "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages", but I can't find it I think it is not a common package.

Can anyone help me with this? and maybe give me a short explanation on how `pip install` works?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please don't link pictures of code or errors. Copy them and paste them (as text!) into the question. Format them as "Code" to make it readable.

Comment: Owh ok thanks, I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dummy interface for RPI.GPIO, in order to try the code on laptop, or coding on laptop for GPIO. It does nothing, it just a dummy interface but it will not prompt any error when debugging on other machine other than Raspi.

Here is the reference:
[Create Fake RPI.GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37780/128358)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you cannot install `RPI.GPIO` is that it is a module for Raspberry Pi. To install `numpy`, I would suggest trying

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools     
pip3 install numpy
```

so that you will work with Python 3. If this still does not work, downloading and installing Anaconda will be useful. After you make sure you installed Anaconda correctly and check `conda` is in path of your terminal, type

```
conda create -n [your_env_name] python=[desired_version] numpy
```

so that it will automatically build the dependencies for `numpy` in your environment.

An example is

```
conda create -n new_env python=3.7 numpy
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I'm using Pycharm as my python IDE do I need another IDE like Anaconda?
Yes RPI.GPIO is for Raspberry Pi but is that possible if I want to edit my code in my laptop which is Windows ?

Comment: Hi, Anaconda can help you build your virtual environment, so you can keep using Pycharm. On Pycharm's project interpreter settings, just choose your conda environment and activate it. It will help you build the wheel for "numpy" and after activating the conda environment, you will still be able to install other packages with pip. "RPI.GPIO" should only work on Raspberry Pi, so you need to change your code to "fake" that module just like  [this example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37780)